# Pass array from class to main

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I am trying to create an array of 10 Employee objects in a separate class file and then access it from my main. I have three separate files. Employee.cpp, Employee.h and EmployeeArray10.h

Employee.cpp is obviously the main, Employee.h holds the constructors, getters, setters for the Employee() class and EmployeeArray10.h is where the array of ten Employee() objects is created. The problem I am having is how do I create and the access the array created in the EmployeeArray10.h file from main() and consequently use the tostring() function from the employee() class on the objects created in the EmployeeArray10.h

I have been staring at this for hours, guidance would be appreciated. Please tell me if this is not clear enough.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Employee.h"
#include "EmployeeArray10.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Employee employee1;
    Employee employee2(001, "Rob", "Address");
    Employee employee3(002, "Tom", "The Street", "Science Dept", 25000.00, "99-CW-4753");

    employee1.tostring();
    employee2.tostring();
    employee3.tostring();

    EmployeeArray10 employeeArray;

    for(int i=0; i <=10; i++){

        employeeArray[i].EmployeeArray10.Employee.tostring();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Employee.h :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{

private:
int number;
string name;
string address;
string department;
double salary;
string regNumber;


// CONSTRUCTOR METHODS
public:
Employee()
{
    setNumber(0);
    setName("");
    setAddress("");
    setDepartment("");
    setSalary(0.0);
    setRegNumber("");
}
Employee(int pNum, string pName, string pAddress)
{
    setNumber(pNum);
    setName(pName);
    setAddress(pAddress);
    setDepartment("");
    setSalary(0.0);
    setRegNumber("");
}
Employee(int pNum, string pName, string pAddress, string pDepartment, double pSalary, string pRegNumber)
{
    setNumber(pNum);
    setName(pName);
    setAddress(pAddress);
    setDepartment(pDepartment);
    setSalary(pSalary);
    setRegNumber(pRegNumber);
}
// SET METHODS
void setNumber(int pNum)
{
    number = pNum;
}
void setName(string pName)
{
    name = pName;
}
void setAddress(string pAddress)
{
    address = pAddress;
}
void setDepartment(string pDepartment)
{
    department = pDepartment;
}
void setSalary(double pSalary)
{
    salary = pSalary;
}
void setRegNumber(string pRegNumber)
{
    regNumber = pRegNumber;
}
// GET METHODS
int getNumber()
{
    return number;
}
string getName()
{
    return name;
}
string getAddress()
{
    return address;
}
string getDepartment()
{
    return department;
}
double getSalary()
{
    return salary;
}
string getRegNumber()
{
    return regNumber;
}
// MISC METHODS
void tostring()
{
    cout << "\n\nEmployee Object\nNumber: " << number <<
    "\nName: " << name <<
    "\nAddress: " << address <<
    "\nDepartment: " << department <<
    "\nSalary: " << salary <<
    "\nTax payable: " << taxPayable(salary) <<
    "\nCar reg. no.: " << regNumber <<"\n\n";

}

double taxPayable(double mSalary){

    double result = 0;

    if (mSalary <= 20000 && mSalary >=1){

        result = mSalary * 0.2;
    }

    else if(mSalary > 20000){

        result = (20000 * 0.2) + ((mSalary - 20000) * 0.4);

    }

    return result;
}
```

};

EmployeeArray10.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class EmployeeArray10{

public:
EmployeeArray10(){

    Employee *newEmpArray = new Employee[10];

        for(int i=0; i <=10; i++){

            newEmpArray[i].setNumber(i+1);

        }

}
```

};

Comment: why are u iterating pass the end of the array?

Comment: @TonyTheLion, be constructive or keep quiet. You've commented on everyone else's post but offered nothing to help.

Comment: @RobEatsEverythingDelaney, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149320/pass-array-from-class-to-main#comment30032366_20149497) sounds like a good suggestion to me.

Comment: whats this site for then if not to ask questions about things you don't understand? If everyone understood coding perfectly this site would be pointless and you lot wouldn't get to be arrogant. What a shame that would be right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has so many flaws in so many ways I don't even know where to begin, but I'll state some basic mistakes for you to begin the learning. You might want to look up the words I highlight:

1. You class EmployeeArray10 has no **member variables**. It has only a constrcutor. No meber variables means it can not have any state or store anything.
2. The constructor allocates memory, never storing the pointer to it anywhere. That means you have a **memory leak** there.
3. In the headers you include standard headers you never use there. Why?
4. In the same headers you have using directives. Never do that in header files. It will spill the namespace all over your project, making namespaces effectively useless.
5. You define *way* to many getters and setters. **Encapsulation** has a reason, you break it by making everything accessible anyways.
6. In both for loops you loop from 0 to 10, *including* 10. Meaning you try to access 11 members where are only 10. Read about loops in your beginner's textbook of choice.
7. `toString()` is a name for a function that turns something into a string. In your case, it does something different. Give your functions meaningful names, not misleading ones.
8. the line `employeeArray[i].EmployeeArray10.Employee.tostring();` makes no sense at all:

   - EmployeeArray10 has no `operator[]`, so `employeeArray[i]` makes no sense. I assume you want to get access to the i'th Employee in that array.
   - Employee has no member variable `EmployeeArray10`, so `employeeArray[i].EmployeeArray10` makes no sense.
   - same for `employeeArray[i].EmployeeArray10.Employee`
   - maybe you meant `employeeArray[i].tostring()`, but people can only guess. The compiler can't, so he will just run away.

To be honest, the whole code looks like you copied and pasted code from somewhere else, not fully understanding what you (or the code) are doing. You should read a good book about the basic concepts in the language and then go on step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Three words: use member variables.

Comment: I see five words here

Answer (score 1):

Your EmployeeArray10 class doesn't return a pointer to the array it creates, making it impossible to access from outside the constructor (and thus also impossible to delete which means you have a memory leak).

Constructors cannot have a return type either. You need to write a deconstructor function for the EmployeeArray10 to fix your memory leak, and then write a function that returns a pointer to the array so that you can actually use it outside the class.

Frankly, just use modern C++ facilities if you can, like a `std::vector<Employee>`.